# Does the Swift Package Manager support regex literals?

Tags: swift, regex, swift-package-manager

I am using the Swift Package Manager, with Swift 5.7.1. I would like to compile code with a regex literal. For example, `main.swift` could be as follows:

```swift
let message = "Hello, world"
print(message.replacing(/[aeiou]/, with: "[vowel]"))
```

I am not at present interested in the output, in with the compilation.

If I create a project in XCode, it works just fine. However, if I try it in the Swift Package Manager (using `swift build`) it obviously does not recognize that `/[aeiou]/` is a regex literal. Instead, I get messages like `'/' is not a prefix unary operator`.

Is there any way to get this to work with the Swift Package Manager, or is it simply not yet supported?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Swift 5.7's regex literals can work when using the Swift Package Manager, but they must be explicitly enabled in your `Package.swift`. By default, the new syntax is disabled since it's a source-breaking language change (due to the existing use of "/" in comment syntax and operators the `/` operator).

Here's an illustrative `Package.swift` that sets "-enable-bare-slash-regex" for all the package targets. I've also included a couple of additional settings that you may want if you're working towards fully adopting Swift 5.7:

```swift
// swift-tools-version: 5.7

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "your-package-name",
  platforms: [...],
  dependencies: [...],
  targets: [
    .target(
      name: "FooBar",
      dependencies: []
    ),
    .testTarget(
      name: "FooBarTests",
      dependencies: [
        "FooBar",
      ]
    ),
  ]
)

for target in package.targets {
  target.swiftSettings = target.swiftSettings ?? []
  target.swiftSettings?.append(
    .unsafeFlags([
      "-Xfrontend", "-warn-concurrency",
      "-Xfrontend", "-enable-actor-data-race-checks",
      "-enable-bare-slash-regex",
    ])
  )
}
```

In a future Swift version and once there’s been time for existing code to transition to Swift 5.7, regex literals will likely be enabled by default.

---

**Swift 5.8 Update**

The [Swift 5.8 release](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Documentation/ReleaseNotes/5.8.md) supports the [piecemeal adoption of upcoming language improvements](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0362-piecemeal-future-features.md). The `enableUpcomingFeature` helps avoid the situation where ["use of unsafe flags make the products containing this target ineligible for use by other packages"](https://docs.swift.org/package-manager/PackageDescription/PackageDescription.html).

```swift
let swiftSettings: [SwiftSetting] = [
    // -enable-bare-slash-regex becomes
    .enableUpcomingFeature("BareSlashRegexLiterals"), 
    // -warn-concurrency becomes
    .enableUpcomingFeature("StrictConcurrency"), 
    .unsafeFlags(["-enable-actor-data-race-checks"], 
        .when(configuration: .debug)),
]

for target in package.targets {
    target.swiftSettings = target.swiftSettings ?? []
    target.swiftSettings?.append(contentsOf: swiftSettings)
}
```