# Can regex literals be used in a Swift script?

Tags: swift, regex, shebang

I would like to make a Swift script with “shebang” notation that uses a regex literal. For example:

```swift
#!/usr/bin/env swift

let message = "Hello, world"
print(message.replacing(/[aeiou]/, with: "[vowel]"))
```

In the question [Does the Swift Package Manager support regex literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75573646/2757533), I learned how to make this code work in the Swift Package Manager.

Could it be made to work as a Swift script, or do I have to wait for future updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in the linked post, regex literals is an opt-in feature for now, and you need to use the `-enable-bare-slash-regex` option.

Just change the shebang to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env swift -enable-bare-slash-regex
```

Comment: Ubuntu error: "use -[v]S to pass options in shebang lines".  The addition of `-S` worked OK for both macOS & Ubuntu `#!/usr/bin/env -S swift -enable-bare-slash-regex` in my use case.

Comment: Alternately, `#!/usr/bin/env -S swift -enable-upcoming-feature BareSlashRegexLiterals` since Swift 5.8