# Running Swift regex example gives many errors

Tags: swift

I never worked with Swift, but now I need to understand how its regex works. So, from this [site](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/getting-started-with-swift-regex/) I took the following example:

```
import Foundation

let regex = /(\w+)\s+(\d+)/

let input = "Tom 123 xyz"
if let result = input.firstMatch(of: regex) {
  print(result.0)  // Tom 123
  print(result.1)  // Tom
  print(result.2)  // 123
}
```

But when I try to run it using this online [compiler](https://www.programiz.com/swift/online-compiler/) I get:

```
swift /tmp/JTkHvt21X2.swift
/tmp/JTkHvt21X2.swift:3:19: error: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
let regex = /(\w+)\s+(\d+)/
                  ^
                  ;
/tmp/JTkHvt21X2.swift:3:13: error: '/' is not a prefix unary operator
let regex = /(\w+)\s+(\d+)/
            ^
/tmp/JTkHvt21X2.swift:3:17: error: '+' is not a postfix unary operator
let regex = /(\w+)\s+(\d+)/
                ^
/tmp/JTkHvt21X2.swift:3:16: error: cannot find 'w' in scope
let regex = /(\w+)\s+(\d+)/
               ^
/tmp/JTkHvt21X2.swift:3:17: error: invalid component of Swift key path
let regex = /(\w+)\s+(\d+)/
                ^
/tmp/JTkHvt21X2.swift:3:20: error: cannot find 's' in scope
let regex = /(\w+)\s+(\d+)/
                   ^
/tmp/JTkHvt21X2.swift:3:20: error: invalid component of Swift key path
let regex = /(\w+)\s+(\d+)/
                   ^
/tmp/JTkHvt21X2.swift:3:27: error: '/' is not a postfix unary operator
let regex = /(\w+)\s+(\d+)/
                          ^
/tmp/JTkHvt21X2.swift:3:25: error: '+' is not a postfix unary operator
let regex = /(\w+)\s+(\d+)/
                        ^
/tmp/JTkHvt21X2.swift:3:24: error: cannot find 'd' in scope
let regex = /(\w+)\s+(\d+)/
                       ^
/tmp/JTkHvt21X2.swift:3:25: error: invalid component of Swift key path
let regex = /(\w+)\s+(\d+)/
                        ^
```

I thought that I use old compiler version and checked it using code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080904/5057736) and got:

```
Hello, Swift 5.8
```

As I understand regex literal are supported from 5.7. Could anyone say what I am doing wrong.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/75615132/5133585 I think you need the `-enable-bare-slash-regex` option when compiling.

Comment: @Sweeper I decided to use swift docker. But I can't find a way how to pass this option to compiler. I tried `swift build -enable-upcoming-feature BareSlashRegexLiterals` and `swift build  -enable-bare-slash-regex` but it didn't work. Could you say how to build with slash regex support?

Comment: Oh you are using SPM. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/75573646/5133585 then.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I did it. Thank you very much for your help!